# ubuntu-sdk on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-sdk

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 (clean install). I now find that I cannot install ubuntu-sdk. I cannot add the ubuntu-sdk ppa because that fails with a message that the repository has no release file

Help greatly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the message that ubuntu-sdk package has no release file because the ubuntu-sdk package has been discontinued in Ubuntu 17.10 and later. The ubuntu-sdk package for Ubuntu 17.10 has also been discontinued in ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa. The last Ubuntu release that has ubuntu-sdk in the default repositories is Ubuntu 16.04.